# Eliminar elementos repetidos de leyenda matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

tengo este código

```
   for (i,j) in list:     
      for k in number:
        if i==k:
          plt.plot([p[i][0],c[j][0]], [p[i][1],c[j][1]], lista_de_colores[k], label='It is %i' %i)
```

Pero me devuelve esta leyenda:

[image]

Y yo solo quiero que por cada color salga solo una vez. Se que se debe al for, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo ya que necesito el for para que salga el color y el nombre de cada uno.

Comment: usa un while dentro de tu for

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar algo más? Porque me he quedado igual

Comment: En la leyenda que muestras, por ejemplo el "It is 2" aparece tres veces, las tres con el mismo color. ¿Aparecen también tres plots del mismo color en la gráfica? ¿Quieres que eso sea así, es decir tres plots diferentes, los tres con el mismo color, pero que aparezcan una sola vez en la leyenda?

Comment: Justo eso, abulafia. Tengo, como bien comentas para It is 2 tres plots del mismo color pero solo quiero que salga una vez en la leyenda, y lo mismo para el resto de plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que básicamente lo que necesitas es la receta para crear tu propia leyenda.

Para ello necesitarás tener alguna estructura de datos con los colores que usa tu gráfica y el texto que quieres que aparezca en la leyenda junto a cada color. Por ejemplo, podría tratarse de una lista de tuplas (color, texto).

Esa información tendrías que extraerla en tu caso de tu lista `lista_de_colores`, y podría ser (si no me equivoco) algo así:

```
info_leyenda = [(color, "It is %i" % i) 
                for i, color in enumerate(lista_de_colores) if i in number]
```

Una vez tienes esta info, pinta tus gráficas igual que antes, pero eliminando de `plt.plot()` el parámetro `label`. Eso crearía en principio una gráfica sin leyenda. Pero luego puedes crear tu propia leyenda con la siguiente receta:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
plt.legend([Line2D([0], [0], color=clave[0], lw=2) for clave in info_leyenda],
           [clave[1] for clave in info_leyenda])
```

### Demo

Ya que yo no tengo tus datos, no puedo pintar tu gráfica. Voy a inventar entonces un ejemplo en el que mostraré tres plots de color naranja (que son la función seno con diferentes amplitudes) y tres de color verde (que son la función coseno con diferentes amplitudes). Añadiré la leyenda con solo esos dos colores.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

# Eje X
time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);

for i in range(1,4):  # Bucle que crea tres plots
  # Plot del seno, naranja
  amplitude   = np.sin(time)*i
  plt.plot(time, amplitude, color = "orange")

  # Plot del coseno, verde
  amplitude   = np.cos(time)*i
  plt.plot(time, amplitude, color = "green")

# Lo anterior aún no tiene leyenda. Añadimos una
info_leyenda = [
    ("orange", "seno"),
    ("green", "coseno")]
plt.legend([Line2D([0], [0], color=clave[0], lw=2) for clave in info_leyenda],
           [clave[1] for clave in info_leyenda])
```

El resultado es:

[image: Grafica]

### Bonus

Creo que puedes simplificar un poco el bucle que pinta tus gráficas. Supongo que `number` es una lista de números y que la misión del bucle `for k in number` es ver si `i` está en esa lista. Puedes escribirlo entonces así:

```
for (i,j) in list:     
  if i in number:
    plt.plot([p[i][0],c[j][0]], [p[i][1],c[j][1]], lista_de_colores[i])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte! Me ha ayudado!

Comment: @Logan Acabo de hacer una edición para simplificar tu bucle que pinta los plots. Y entonces me he dado cuenta de que en la leyenda no han de aparecer todos los colores, sino solo aquellos correspondientes a los números que están en la lista `numeros`. Así que he cambiado la parte donde construyo `info_leyenda`, al principio de la respuesta.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Voy a echarle un vistazo a eso nuevo que comentas.